# Javascript: Add an extra checkbox next to an existing checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have this checkbox created using `forms.py`. I did not write html code, it's resulted rendering `forms.py`.

```
<div id="div_id_diag-diagnosis_option" class="form-group">
<label for="id_diag-diagnosis_option_0" class="control-label col-md-3 requiredField">
Option<span class="asteriskField">*</span></label>
<div class="controls col-md-8"><label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="diag-diagnosis_option" id="id_diag-diagnosis_option_1" value="b" >b</label>
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="diag-diagnosis_option" id="id_diag-diagnosis_option_2" value="a" >a</label>
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="diag-diagnosis_option" id="id_diag-diagnosis_option_3" value="c" >c</label>
</div></div>
```

Using javascript I want to create an extra checkbox near to every option. For example if a user selects b option, on the right of b I want a new checkbox to be added.

Any ideas please?

Comment: use jquery onclick event  and append a checkbox...

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone' Can you give me a simple example please?

Comment: Do you want this to happen indefinitely? (eg. A clicked = B appears; B clicked = C appears; C clicked = D appears and so on) Or only once?

Comment: @Fester If a clicked, a new checkbox is created and appeared next to a. A,B,C should be appeared from the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this adds a checkbox next to the checkbox you selected

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
   $(this).after('<input type="checkbox">');
})
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ah4tvwLw/1/)

Comment: Insert this line $(this).after('<input type="checkbox">'); before the alert and it should work @zinon

Comment: it will add the checkbox, but its not visible, inspect with chrome or firebug

Comment: I think it is because there is no label.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
     $(this).after('<input type="checkbox" name="diag-diagnosis_option" id="id_diag-diagnosis_option_2" value="a" >');
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE CODE SAMPLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/muhammadusmaann/ah4tvwLw/21/)

Comment: Thank You. I do not to have a button and only next to the selected option (or optionS) a new checkbox will be appeared not to all.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
    if ($(this).prop('checked'))
    $(this).after('<input type="checkbox">');
});
```